# input control like a 4 x 25 LCD display

Tags: c#, input, lcd

in a .net app

I need a control 4 rows @ 25 characters - looking like a LCD display. Actually the input is later displayed on a LCD in a car ..

I am thinking to just use a datagridview, each column can just hold one character, shift focus to the next cell after a character is entered, etc.

Any (better) ideas?

Thanks
Oskar

Comment: Why not use `char[4,25]` ?

Comment: ...and a fixed width font

Comment: What system Winforms, WPF?

Comment: I am using WF. Editing something like char[x,y] in a textbox control will not give me the optics of an LCD. Especially not a rectangle around each "position"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multidimensional array for the screen:

```
char[,] display = new char[4, 25];
```